# Limit each user can only trigger one build in a same Jenkins job(project)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have one Jenkins pipeline job which can run concurrent builds. This job will trigger by all users (triggered by user-A, user-B, User-C etc.)
Now I want to **limit each user can only trigger one build**. For example: 
If user-A already triggered one build which is running, the next build need to line up or pending, but any other users still can triggered new build.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to go this route, you will have to put the state outside of Jenkins. A possible similar workflow is when provisioning dev boxes. Say if you do that using AWS, you can assign tags like email into the provisioned instance, that way if a user tries to run another provision job but with an existing resource already allocated(or is being allocated), Jenkins has a way to query AWS via API to not proceed with the build.

Comment: using lockable resources directly wont work because the job takes a slot while it waits for the lock to free; so you still end up with multiple jobs running per user, but now only one is actually executing.

you can solve that by having a job in front of the one being managed;  have that lock per user while starting the underlying job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by combining:

- [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin)
- [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin)

Use the Generic Webhook Trigger to get the email of the pusher. If using GitHub that JSONPath expression would be `$.pusher.email`.

Use the Lockable Resource Plugin to allocate a resource named like that email.